# Android: returning to main activity from GLSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-activity, renderer

I don't understand the flow between my main activity and a OpenGL renderer.

When my app starts, the user will see a very pretty layout that I've made with a button that says "start rendering." When user clicks the button, he/she will be transferred to a renderer view that draws an awesome picture. Then when the picture is completed, I want to return to the main screen (the one with the button), but I don't know how.

I tried calling setContentView(R.layout.activity_run) from GLRenderer, but obviously it doesn't work. I then tried to make a function, Run.endRendering(), that was a static method and was called from inside GLRenderer. Run.endRendering() was supposed to call setContentView(R.layout.activity_run) in hopes that it would then transfer the view back to the main screen, but since R.endRendering() is a static method, it can't call the non-static method of setContentView().

So now I'm completely lost. Could someone shed some light on the subject?

These are the skeletons that I have.

Main activity:

```java
public class Run extends Activity
{
    private GLSurfaceView glSurface;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_run);

        // in here I mess with the main layout view the user
        // is supposed to see. when he/she clicks on a button
        // he/she will be transferred to the opengl view

        // on button click:
        glSurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glSurface.setRenderer(new GLRenderer());

        setContentView(glSurface);
    }
}
```

And the renderer:

```java
public class GLRenderer implements Renderer
{
    // onSurfaceCreated, onDrawFrame, onSurfaceChanged, etc.

    // the action happens here. From here I want to return to
    // the main activity that created this renderer.
}
```

Comment: Use 2 activities, one for your main and one for your Open GL.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is make your GLSurfaceView part of a layout for that activity.
The UI thread of the activity keeps running. Create a handler in it which will take care of removing the GLSurfaceView from the layout and display your normal non-opengl views.

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         // remove surfaceview from layout and show non-opengl views
    }
};
```

You can then pass a reference of your activity (probably using an interface) to the GLRenderer. Which can call.

```
activity.mainHandler.sendMessage(msg)
```